Loading Data with Entity Framework: Data Loss in List
public async Task<ApiResponse> GetAllGroupsAsync(Guid studentId)
    {
        var groups = await _dbContext.ProjectGroups
                                       .Include(x => x.StudentGroups)
                                       .ThenInclude(x => x.Student).ThenInclude(x => x.User)
                                       .Where(x => x.StudentGroups.Any(y => y.StudentId == studentId))
                                       .ToListAsync();
        
        if (groups.Count == 0)
            return new ApiResponse()
            {
                Status = "Error",
                Message = "No groups found"
            };
        List<GetManyGroupModelResponse> result = new List<GetManyGroupModelResponse>();
        foreach (var group in groups)
        {
            var members = group.StudentGroups.Select(sg => new MemberOfGroupModelResponse()
            {
                StudentId = sg.StudentId,
                UserName = sg.Student.User.UserName,
                Email = sg.Student.User.Email,
                Name = sg.Student.User.FirstName + " " + sg.Student.User.LastName
            }).ToList();
            result.Add(new GetManyGroupModelResponse()
            {
                GroupId = group.GroupId,
                Topic = group.Topic,
                GroupName = group.GroupName,
                Members = members
            });
        }

        return new ApiResponse()
        {
            Status = "Success",
            Message = "Groups found",
            Data = result!
        };
    }

public class GetManyGroupModelResponse
{
    public Guid GroupId { get; set; }
    public string? GroupName { get; set; }
    public string? Topic { get; set; }
    public List<MemberOfGroupModelResponse>? Members { get; set; }
}

public class MemberOfGroupModelResponse
{
    public Guid StudentId { get; set; }
    public string? UserName { get; set; }
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public string? Email { get; set; }
}

When I run this code, the StudentGroups list in the first ProjectGroup is lost, and only the list for the last ProjectGroup is retained. I want all ProjectGroup instances to have the corresponding StudentGroups list for the specified studentId because I created 3 group with its.
How can I ensure that the StudentGroups list for all ProjectGroup instances is retained without being overwritten?
Is there a better way to load this data without causing data loss?
